# Receiving and processing SMS via GSM Modem

Tags: vb.net

i have GSM modem (ZTE MF112) connected via USB port. I can send and receive SMS with this modem through serial port but i want to monitor the modem continuously for received SMS. if an SMS received, i want to connect the database, search the required information and send it back to the sender.

i need the whole process auto-method without any human interference. 
like:

A function which will monitor the Serial port
if an SMS is received, it will call another function and pass the queried information to it and that function will connect the database. if information is found that information will be return otherwise some message will be return to the first function.

Note: The code is needed in VB.Net
some body help me plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I have added a timer to my application and set its delay to 5000 ms (5 s). Inside the `timer_tick` event I wrote the code to check and list up unread SMS from the modem.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you make a loop which check for for any unread messages after certain time period like 5 sec or 10 sec if there is any unread message it gets it from modem parse it and display it